# Code igniter routing for dynamic id

Tags: php, url-routing, codeigniter-routing

How can I route to specific URL for URL having dynamic id. Suppose orginal URL is

```
 http:localhost/c2c/init/product/5     // here 5 is the id of the product.
```

*In route.php*

```
 $route["product/iphone-on-sale"] = "init/product/5";
```

But its not routing to `http:localhost/c2c/product/iphone-on-sale` when when original URL is entered.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
$route["product/iphone-on-sale/(:num)"] = "init/product/$1";
```

and your url will be

```
http://localhost/c2c/product/iphone-on-sale/5
```